# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have an Edit controller action  (Httpost) with following code:

```
 var person = membershipService.GetPersonByUserName(userName, out userAccount);

            if (!email.Equals(person.Email)) {
                person.Email = email;               
                CRRep.UpdatePersonEmail(person);
            }
 public void UpdatePersonEmail(Person person)
        {              
            try
            {                     
               context.Entry(person).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
               context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But I am getting following error:
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
Please suggest me solution to it.

Comment: How do you instantiate and dispose `context`? Do you have one context per request, multiple contexts per request or one context per multiple requests?

Comment: I have one context for all requests.

Comment: @Slauma How can I dispose the context If I have multiples. How to modify this code?

Comment: You probably have a mess with context lifetime and multiple contexts. As far as I know the error indicates that you're trying to attach an entity to a context but it is already attached to another context (from a former request perhaps?). Can you show how and where are you doing the "new Context..."? Disposing should basically happen "at the same level" = service or controller or application or whatever level.

Comment: @Slauma I am creating it at the top of repository like this: public class UserAccountRepository
    {
        CreditRegistryContext context = new CreditRegistryContext();  and UpdatePersonEmail is at the bottom of this repository class

Comment: And `membershipService`??? Does it have its own context? BTW: You can edit your question (use "Edit" link below your question) to put additional infos into your question. That's much better than adding those infos only as comment here.

Comment: @Slauma, Thanks your trcik worked. I needed to use Service instead of calling repo directly. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here is what is happening:

In your membershipService implementation, you are querying context A to get the person entity.

Then in UpdatePersonEmail you are attaching the person to context B.

There are a few ways to solve this. The simplest is probably calling .AsNoTracking() when you query context A in the membershipService class. This way, the Person entity returned by the service will not be attached to context A:

```
context.People.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(p => p.UserName == userName);
```

Another way would be to inject the context using an IoC container, so that both the UpdatePersonEmail method's class has the same context instance as the membershipService class.